# Xamarin Forms : getting the Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0 in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting this exception when running on iPhone , its working fine on Android. Earlier its was working fine . Xamarin forms version is 3.0.0.446417. I google also but found its happing because of delete or clearing the ObservableCollection but I am not calling clear() method on ObservableCollection. I am using the synfusion Listview.
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (33) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Please help !!

Comment: Are you adding or removing elements from the list?

Comment: Did u get the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the items one by one in a for loop.  It worked for me.